# How to backup SQL database without users and stored procedures

Tags: backup, sql, stored-procedures

I have a database which i need to take backup monthly / or by running an script.
I need to backup the data and structure only. I don't want to backup stored procedures and users for example...

I have tried "generating script" ... but i cannot restore to a test database to achieve my goal.
The goal is to pass the backup file to another company so I don't want them to have the stored procedures...
Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What kind of database are we talking about? mysql, postgresql, sqlite, sql server, oracledb?

Comment: Which database server on which platform?

Comment: Oops. Sorry forgot to mention it. @Markus its MS SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  You're probably going to have to:

1. Back up the database.
2. Restore it with a new name.
3. Delete the users and stored procedures out of the new database.
4. Back it up again to a new file.
5. Send the resulting backup file to the other company.

You can use this query ([found on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/219510/2409749)) to find the procedures:

```
select * 
  from DatabaseName.information_schema.routines 
 where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```